# googlecloudsdk.core.exceptions.RequiresAdminRightsError: You cannot perform this action because you do not have permission

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sdk

I am trying to install `google-cloud-sdk` in `ubuntu-18.04`. I am following offical docs given [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/quickstart-linux). When I run `./google-cloud-sdk/install.sh` I get following error:-

```
Welcome to the Google Cloud SDK!

To help improve the quality of this product, we collect anonymized usage data
and anonymized stacktraces when crashes are encountered; additional information
is available at <https://cloud.google.com/sdk/usage-statistics>. This data is
handled in accordance with our privacy policy
<https://policies.google.com/privacy>. You may choose to opt in this
collection now (by choosing 'Y' at the below prompt), or at any time in the
future by running the following command:

    gcloud config set disable_usage_reporting false

Do you want to help improve the Google Cloud SDK (y/N)?  N

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vineet/./google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/install.py", line 225, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/vineet/./google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/install.py", line 200, in main
    Prompts(pargs.usage_reporting)
  File "/home/vineet/./google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/install.py", line 123, in Prompts
    scope=properties.Scope.INSTALLATION)
  File "/home/vineet/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/properties.py", line 2406, in PersistProperty
    config.EnsureSDKWriteAccess()
  File "/home/vineet/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/config.py", line 198, in EnsureSDKWriteAccess
    raise exceptions.RequiresAdminRightsError(sdk_root)
googlecloudsdk.core.exceptions.RequiresAdminRightsError: You cannot perform this action because you do not have permission to modify the Google Cloud SDK installation directory [/home/vineet/google-cloud-sdk].

Re-run the command with sudo: sudo /home/vineet/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud ...
```

I tried to search it on stackoverflow and github-issues but in vain.

Would appreciate any hint to solve it.

Comment: You might be missing  sudo  to run the installer.

Comment: @AdiDembak with `sudo` it worked with warning `WARNING: You appear to be running this script as root. This may cause 
the installation to be inaccessible to users other than the root user.`

Comment: Where you able to successfully install the Google Cloud SDK after using `sudo` to run the `install.ssh` script? Notice that you could also use the package with the `apt-get` command as instructed [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/downloads-apt-get).

Comment: @DanielOcando `sudo` worked for me. Thanks for `apt-get` based method

Comment: Adding the answer as a community wiki.

Answer (score 0):

As stated on the error message.

> Re-run the command with sudo: sudo /home/vineet/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud ...

The install.sh script should be run using `sudo`.

There are also other alternatives to install the Google Cloud SDK in Ubuntu 18.04 just as installing the package with apt-get as explained on the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/downloads-apt-get).